# How to create a paypal recurring payment with an initial amount to pay?

Tags: php, paypal

I am currently creating a paypal payment with recurring support. I want it
in such a way that there is an initial payment made.

Example :

- 30$ - initial payment
- 10$ - recurring monthly payment

The initial payment is charge upon checkout. I'm using the html standard
integration process.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with Website Payments Standard (the 'HTML standard integration process' I assume you use). Simply include a trial period within the subscription, and start charging X days from when subscriptions ends.

See the [subscription variables here](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables#id08A6HI00JQU).

Answer (score 4):

Using paypal NVP API for PHP, you can send the initial payment to paypal like this.

```
$nvpstr="&AMT=10&CREDITCARDTYPE=$creditCardType&ACCT=$creditCardNumber&EXPDATE=".         $padDateMonth.$expDateYear."&CVV2=$cvv2Number&FIRSTNAME=$firstName&LASTNAME=$lastName&STREET=$address1&CITY=$city&STATE=$state".
"&ZIP=$zip&COUNTRYCODE=US&CURRENCYCODE=$currencyCode&PROFILESTARTDATE=$profileStartDate&DESC=$profileDesc&BILLINGPERIOD=$billingPeriod&BILLINGFREQUENCY=$billingFrequency&TOTALBILLINGCYCLES=$totalBillingCycles&INITAMT=30.00";


$resArray=hash_call("CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile",$nvpstr);
```

parameter `INITAMT` specifies the initial payment amount

Comment: You're a life saver with `INITAMT`. I probably don't need to say that PayPal's API documentation doesn't mention this anywhere... at least anywhere where it could be easily found. I'm wondering how someone with so confusing API and docs gets so popular...

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer please? I need this! Please have a look at the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25997058/how-to-set-mixture-of-recurring-and-one-time-payment-in-paypal/25998385?noredirect=1#comment40720226_25998385

Comment: Excellent! YEARS and I just ran across this now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I too switched from website payment's pro to html integration and unfortunately initial amount option is not available in HTML version. If you can switch website payments pro and use API then you can have the option of initial amount (I had to switch because API is not allowed on Israel paypal accounts) otherwise the only option you have in HTML is trial periods.

Answer (score -1):

But on the below link the INTAMT is not proper way to deduct initial payment 
[Paypal recrurring payments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918129/paypal-recrurring-payments)

So please put your thoughts.