# Paypal recrurring payments

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, recurring-billing

I am using PAYPAL recurring payments for subscriptions and it is working well in case :

- When user subscribes then **INIT AMT, BILLING AMT, BILLING PERIOD** has been set.

> $request['CURRENCYCODE'] = ''USD;
>   $request['AMT'] = $amount;
>   $request['INITAMT'] = $amount;
>           $request['BILLINGPERIOD'] = $billingPeriod;  // Month
>           $request['BILLINGFREQUENCY'] = $billingFrequency; // 1
>   $request['PROFILESTARTDATE'] = date('Y-m-d\Th:m:s', strtotime('+' . $billingFrequency ." ". $billingPeriod));

User would be charged with INIT AMT and then after the specific period (I have set INIT because I need **TRANSACTION_ID**. Paypal is only deducting the amount after specific period, not instantly on profile creation). But This case is OK.

For eg : User subscribes on on **4th/june** with amount **$10**, with recurring period '**Month**'. Then User will be charged on **4th/july**

---

### Now concern is :

I want to make a profile of user but not to deduct **INIT AMT** on profile creation, just want to deduct the recurring billing amount instantly when User creates a profile.

Instance : User subscribe on 4th/june and I want to charge after **XX days**(eg: if 10 days then on 14th/june).

I am not aware of such variable (if any) that paypal have to fulfill my requirement.
Paypal tigers please update me. Glad if anyone could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't process an `INITAMT` as an Authorization so that wouldn't be an easy solution. If you're passing `INITAMT` it will always be billed right away and you can't have a Recurring Profile charge right away.

The Recurring Profiles are billed in groups during the day so there isn't a guarantee that it will be charged right away.

You can use Instant Payment Notification (IPN) to get an update with the transaction ID when the Profile is charged. That may help you out. You can remove the `INITAMT` variable and value and wait for the IPN post to update your records.

Comment: @paypal_patrik Thanks for replying. I am already using IPN for updations. I am using INITAMT because I need to charge user instantly and I realized that creating recurring profile isn't charging instantly (as you say) and even isn't charging on that day or next. It charge the user after specific period set in profile (let say if profile is created on 7/june then paypal would charge on 7/july (I realize this thing)). I need to charge user in advance (on the time of profile creation).

Comment: The Recurring Payment starts to bill the buyer on the date you have set for the "PROFILESTARTDATE". If you don't have that set to be a month ahead of time we won't attempt to bill them until then.

Comment: I guess I am pretty close to my concern.Please clear my one confusion, if "PROFILESTARTDATE" => date('Y-m-d\Th:m:s') // i.e today with period of  "Month", then when would paypal deduct amount from buyer's account.

Comment: If you set the "PROFILESTARTDATE" for a new Recurring Profile to be today it will be billed today but not at the specific time you mention. If the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API call is received late the in the day the billing may occur the following day.